# Quickly Render Bytes to Canvas with a Color Palette

Tags: java, performance, canvas, graphics, bufferedimage

While working on a Java application which requires rendering sprites, I thought that, instead of loading a .png or .jpg file as an `Image` or `BufferedImage`, I could load up a `byte[]` array containing indices for a color palette(16 colors per palette, so two pixels per `byte`), then render that.

The method I currently have generates a `BufferedImage` from the `byte[]` array and color palette while initializing, taking extra time to initialize but running smoothly after that, which works fine, but there are only 4 sprites in the program so far. I'm worried that when there are 100+ sprites, storing all of them as `BufferedImages` will be too taxing on the memory. And not only would that mean 1 `BufferedImage` per sprite, but actually 1 image for each sprite/palette combination I'd want to use.

This function creates the BufferedImage:

```
protected BufferedImage genImage(ColorPalette cp, int width, int height){ //Function to generate BufferedImage to render from the byte[]
    BufferedImage ret = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); //Create the Image to return
    for(int j=0; j<height; j++){ //Run a for loop for each pixel
        for(int i=0; i<width; i++){
            int index = (j * width + i)/2; //Get the index of the needed byte
            int value = image[index] & 0x00ff; //Convert to "unsigned byte", or int
            byte thing; //declare actual color index as byte
            if(i % 2 == 0)thing = (byte)((value & 0b11110000) >>> 4); //If it's an even index(since it starts with 0, this includes the 1st one), get the first 4 bits of the value
            else thing = (byte)(value & 0b00001111); //If it's odd, get the last four bits
            ret.setRGB(i, j, cp.getColor(thing & 0x00ff).getRGB()); //Set the pixel in the image to the value in the Color Palette
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And this one actually renders it to the screen:

```
public void render(Graphics g, int x, int y){ //Graphics to render to and x/y coords
    g.drawImage(texture, x, y, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, null); //Render it
}
```

I've experimented with another method that renders from the `byte[]` directly w/o the need for a `BufferedImage`, which should theoretically succeed in saving memory by avoiding use of a `BufferedImage` for each sprite, but it ended up being very, very slow. It took several seconds to render each frame w/ at most 25 sprites to render on the screen! Note that `g` is a `Graphics` object.

```
private void drawSquare(int x, int y, int scale, Color c){ //Draw each "pixel" to scale
    if(g == null){ //If null, quit
        return;
    }
    g.setColor(c); //Set the color
    for(int i=x; i<x+scale; i++){ //Loop through each pixel
        if(i<0)continue;
        for(int j=y; j<y+scale; j++){
            if(j<0)continue;
            g.fillRect(x, y, scale, scale); //Fill the rect to make the "pixel"
        }
    }
}

public void drawBytes(byte[] image, int x, int y, int width, int height, int scale, ColorPalette palette){ //Draw a byte[] image with given byte[], x/y coords, width/height, scale, and color palette
    if(image.length < width * height / 2){ //If the image is too small, exit
        return;
    }
    for(int j=0; j<height; j++){ //Loop through each pixel
        for(int i=0; i<width; i++){
            int index = (j * width + i)/2; //Get index
            int value = image[index]; //get the byte
            byte thing; //get the high or low value depending on even/odd
            if(i % 2 == 0)thing = (byte)((value & 0b11110000) >>> 4);
            else thing = (byte)(value & 0b00001111);
            drawSquare((int)(x + scale * i), (int)(y + scale * j), scale, palette.getColor(thing)); //draw the pixel
        }
    }
}
```

So is there a more efficient way to render these `byte[]` arrays w/o the need for `BufferedImage`'s? Or will it really not be problematic to have several hundred `BufferdImage`'s loaded into memory?

EDIT: I've also tried doing the no-BufferedImage methods, but with `g` as the one large BufferedImage to which everything is rendered, and is then rendered to the `Canvas`. The primary difference is that `g.fillRect(...` is changed to `g.setRGB(...` in that method, but it was similarly slow.

EDIT: The images I'm dealing with are 16x16 and 32x32 pixels.

Comment: BufferedImage takes up very little memory, aside from the raster data (your byte array).  I doubt you'd notice any difference from this optimization.

Answer (score 0):

If memory usage is your main concern, I'd use `BufferedImage`s with `IndexColorModel` (`TYPE_BYTE_BINARY`). This would perfectly reflect your `byte[] image` and `ColorPalette`, and waste very little memory. They will also be reasonably fast to draw.

This approach will use about 1/8th of the memory used by the initial use of `TYPE_INT_RGB` `BufferedImage`s, because we retain the 4 bits per pixel, instead of 32 bits (an `int` is 32 bits) per pixel (plus some overhead for the palette, of course).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] palette = new byte[16 * 3]; // 16 color palette without alpha
    byte[] pixels = new byte[(16 * 16 * 4) / 8]; // 16 * 16 * 4 bit

    Random random = new Random(); // For test purposes, just fill arrays with random data
    random.nextBytes(palette);
    random.nextBytes(pixels);

    // Create ColorModel & Raster from palette and pixels
    IndexColorModel cm = new IndexColorModel(4, 16, palette, 0, false, -1); // -1 for no transparency
    DataBufferByte buffer = new DataBufferByte(pixels, pixels.length);
    WritableRaster raster = Raster.createPackedRaster(buffer, 16, 16, 4, null);

    // Create BufferedImage from CM and Raster
    final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, cm.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);

    System.out.println("image: " + image); // "image: BufferedImage@...: type = 12 ..."

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
 }
```

The above code will create fully opaque (`Transparency.OPAQUE`) images, that will occupy the entire 16 x 16 pixel block.

If you want bitmask (`Transparency.BITMASK`) transparency, where all pixels are either fully opaque or fulle transparent, just change the last parameter in the `IndexColorModel` to the palette index you want to be fully transparent.

```
int transparentIndex = ...;
IndexColorModel cm = new IndexColorModel(4, 16, palette, 0, false, transparentIndex);
// ...everything else as above
```

This will allow your sprites to have any shape you want.

If you want translucent pixels (`Transparency.TRANSLUCENT`), where pixels can be semi-transparent, you can also have that. You will then have to change the `palette` array to `16 * 4` entries, and include a sample for the alpha value as the 4th sample for each entry (quadruple). Then invoke the `IndexColorModel` constructor with the last parameter set to `true` (`hasAlpha`):

```
byte[] palette = new byte[16 * 4]; // 16 color palette with alpha (translucency)

// ...

IndexColorModel cm = new IndexColorModel(4, 16, palette, 0, true); // true for palette with alpha samples
// ...everything else as above
```

This will allow smoother gradients between the transparent and non-transparent parts of the sprites. But with only 16 colors in the palette, you won't have many entries available for transparency.

Note that it is possible to re-use the `Raster`s and `IndexColorModel`s here, in all of the above examples, to save further memory for images using the same palette, or even images using the same image data with different palettes. There's one caveat though, that is the images sharing rasters will be "live views" of each other, so if you make any changes to one, you will change them all. But if your images are never changed, you could exploit this fact.

---

That said, the above really is a compromise between saving memory and having "reasonable" performance. If performance (ie. frames per second) is more important, just ignore the memory usage, and create `BufferedImage`s that are compatible with your graphics card's/the OS's native pixel layout. You can do this, by using `component.createCompatibleImage(...)` (where `component` is a `JComponent` subclass) or `gfxConfig.createCompatibleImage(...)` (where `gfxConfig` is a `GraphicsConfiguration` obtained from the local `GraphicsEnvironment`).

Comment: Is there a way to do this, but allow transparent pixels?

Comment: PS: There was a bug in the `IndexColorModel` constructor initially. The last parameter should have been `-1` for no transparency.